# Clearing List throws exception after deleting objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list of objects that I have added to my list. I am now destroying the objects and after that I am clearing my list. But my list throws these errors mentioning that it has lost its references and does not clear it.

> ObjectDisposedException: SerializedProperty outline.Array.data[0] has disappeared!
> InvalidOperationException: The operation is not possible when moved past all properties (Next returned false)

So how does one destroy objects and then clear the list to null?

```
public GameObject parent;
public List<GameObject> myObj = new List<GameObject>(); //There are contents of parent's children inside this

void Start(){
    foreach (Transform child in parent.transform) {
            Destroy (child.gameObject);
        }

    myObj.Clear(); //Does not work
    myObj = new List<GameObject> (); //Does not work
}
```

Comment: From the code you posted, it looks like you're destroying the list itself the first thing when you enter the `for` loop. Shouldn't you destroy each element first? e.g.: `Destroy(myObj[i])`?

Comment: sorry that was my mistake, i had not uploaded my full code. It is now updated.

Comment: From what you have posted now, it is unclear how your `myObj` and your `parent` are associated to each other. What is the content of `myObj`?

Comment: Basically some of the contents inside myObj is that of children found inside of parent.

Comment: If `parent` is actually the parent of the object with this script, then your `Start()` method is going to destroy the object that it's being called from.

Comment: @Foggzie no .. why should this be the case? The `parent` itself is nowhere destroyed in OP's code .. only direct children of it

Comment: Where and how exactly is this called? Sounds like something related to an Inspector misbehaving .. if this is e.g. called as a result of some interaction with an Inspector it could cause this kind of issue

Comment: @derHugo If this script is on a child object under `parent` and the script is destroying the children of `parent`, then yes it absolutely will.

Comment: ah now I got you .. true ^^ Wouldn't cause this exception though .. the exception is related to Inspector code and the serialized properties

Comment: @derHugo That's a good question and I believe you are correct in your assumption that something related to the Inspector or a custom Editor script is at play. My point was mostly that it's very possible for this this script to effectively call `Destroy` on `this.gameObject` then continuing to operate which is usually a recipe for a bad time.

Comment: @Yidi A stack trace of those exceptions could provide important context.

Comment: @derHugo yeah exactly in the inspector window :D But I have found a solution, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find was by using "using System.Linq".
This is how I did it, firstly removed from list through "Take" keyword and then cleared it.

```
foreach (Transform child in parent.transform) {
            Destroy (child.gameObject);
        }

    myObj = myObj.Take (myObj.Count).ToList ();
```

Comment: that isn't really a solution ... `myObj.Take (myObj.Count).ToList();` is **not** clearing the list  ... `Take` does not "remove" items ... you should end up with a list full of invalid items .. basically the same as `myObj = new List<GameObject>(myObj);`

Comment: but I have tested it and it clears the list. Also does not throw any exceptions like before.

Comment: well for instance we don't really see how you are adding items to the list .. but it should not be getting cleared by your code since that is not how `Take` works ... https://dotnetfiddle.net/z0Bx47 .. why do you think you need a new list instance in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to throw that in hoping it'll work. Why not try the :

```
try{

foreach (Transform child in parent.transform) {
            Destroy (child.gameObject);
        }

    myObj.Clear(); //Does not work
    myObj = new List<GameObject> (); //Does not work

}catch{Exception exception}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).